# Proving that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x - \frac{1}{x}) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx.$

Tags: calculus

Consider $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be a continuous
function such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ exists. I would like to
prove that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x - \frac{1}{x}) dx =
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx.$$
I decided to tackle it in cases.
In particular, I started out with the case where $f$ was linear. We see that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) - f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(\frac{1}{x}
\right) dx.$$
This problem then boils down into proving that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) dx = 0.$$
we set $u = \frac{1}{x} \implies du = \frac{-1}{x^2} dx.$ However, I am
having problems simplifying the term inside the integral into a function of
$u$. Any suggestions on this case? And any recommendations on the case where
$f$ is not linear?

Comment: The case $f$ is linear could be good to get a sense for the problem, but it's unlikely to help because the case "$f$ is not linear" is probably as hard as the original question.

Comment: *Hint.* Split the original integral into to parts, one from $-\infty$ to $0$ (which we call $I_1$) and the other from $0$ to $\infty$ (which we call $I_2$). Now apply the substitution $x \mapsto -1/x$ to $I_1$ and simplify the resulting expression for $I_1 + I_2$ using another substitution. Also I am pretty sure this is asked several times before with some nice generalizations, so you may want to check them.

Comment: @SangchulLee While you were writing your comment I was writing my answer. It's the same idea.

Comment: The only linear functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are $f(x)=mx$ (or in elementary algebra we sometimes say $f(x)=mx+b$ is because the graph is a line, but this isn't additive), in which case $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ doesn't exist. If you replace "linear" with "additive" then we'd probably have to involve measure theory (and $f$ wouldn't be continuous).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mc{J} & =
\color{#f00}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{x - {1 \over x}}\,\dd x}\ =\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{x - {1 \over x}} +
\mrm{f}\pars{-x + {1 \over x}}}\,\dd x}^{\ds{=\ \mc{J}}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=} \,\,\,
\int_{\infty}^{0}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{{1 \over x} - x} +
\mrm{f}\pars{-\,{1 \over x} + x}}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{{1 \over x} - x} +
\mrm{f}\pars{-\,{1 \over x} + x}}\,{1 \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}_{\ds{=\ \mc{J}}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mc{J} & = {\mc{J} + \mc{J} \over 2} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{{1 \over x} - x} +
\mrm{f}\pars{-\,{1 \over x} + x}}\,\pars{1 + {1 \over x^{2}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{t\ \equiv\ 1/x - x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{t} + \mrm{f}\pars{-t}}\,
\pars{-\,\dd t} = \color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\end{align}

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to reproduce the last step... could you expand?

Comment: @b00nheT Note that
$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,\mathrm{f}\left(t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,\mathrm{f}\left(-t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
$

Comment: Thanks @Dr.MV I guess sometimes I lost some time because I try to write clearly everything.

Comment: Felix, I just posted a solution with another way forward.  It's always amazing to see that two different approaches lead to the same end point. -Mark

Comment: @FelixMarin. Yeah... for some reason I couldn't see that. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

> **METHODOLOGY $1$:**

First, we split the integral as

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\,dx&=\int_{0}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\,dx +\int_0^\infty f\left(-x+\frac1x\right)\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

In the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, we enforce the substitution $x\to e^x$ and in the second integral, we enforce the substitution $x\to e^{-x}$.  Proceeding, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(2\sinh(x)\right)\,e^x\,dx +\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(2\sinh(x)\right)\,e^{-x}\,dx \\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(2\sinh(x))\,2\cosh(x)\,dx\tag2
\end{align}$$

Finally, we enforce the substitution $2\sinh(x)\to x$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ to obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$$

as was to be shown!

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$:**

We begin with the expression given in $(1)$.  In the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, we enforce the substitution $x-\frac1x\to x$, while in the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ we enforce the substitution $-x+\frac1x \to x$.  Proceeding, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x\right)\,\left(\frac12+\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)\,dx +\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x\right)\,\left(\frac12-\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)\,dx \\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: +1. We usually use this substitution in gaussian integrals too. Nice job.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you my friend!  Much appreciative.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to click the +1. Fixed.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you!  I added a second approach for fun.

Answer (score 4):

$x-\frac1x=u\implies\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}u$
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\int_0^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-\infty}^0f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x
+\frac12\int_{-\infty}^0f\left(x-\frac1x\right)\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u+\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{5}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: split up domain of integration
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto-\frac1x$
$(4)$: average $(2)$ and $(3)$
$(5)$: substitute $x-\frac1x=u$
$(6)$: algebra

Comment: This answer got my vote for being the cleanest, both notationally and computationally.